# use regular expression or escape characters with pandas startswith function

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe containing column like this:

```
col_1                
W (2) L / W (1) L 
W (1) D / W (2) L
NaN
W (1) L
W (2) D / W (1) D
W (1) D
```

I want to select rows with values starting with `W (1) L` or `W (2) L`  or `W (2) D`
so the result will be:

```
col_1                
W (2) L / W (1) L 
W (1) L
W (2) D / W (1) D
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
df.loc[df.col_1.str.startswith('W \(1\) L')]
```

and this didn't worked:

```
df.loc[df.col_1.str.contains('^W\(L\).+', regex=True)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using str.contains:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].str.contains('^W \([12]\) L|^W \(2\) D', regex=True, na=False), :]
```

Once the regex is correct, the trick is to pass `na=False` so that the `df.loc[]` functions correctly - otherwise you'll get an error for the NaN value.

Answer (score 1):

An example using `str.match`:

```
df['col_1'].replace(np.nan, 'none', inplace=True)
df[df['col_1'].str.match(r'^W\s\((1\)\sL|2\)\sL|2\)\sD)')]
```

In preparation, the first line cleans the data a bit and replaces any `NaN` values with a `'none'` string. Then the regex takes care of the filtering, in line two.

Output:

```
               col_1
0  W (2) L / W (1) L
3            W (1) L
4  W (2) D / W (1)
```